# Refactoring related nested if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create 2 related models inside my create method, where the 2nd model is created using `model1.model2s.build`. The `model*_params` is just Rails 4 strong parameters.

So I have this set of code in my create method:

```
def create
  @model1 = current_user.model1.build(model1_params)

  if @model1.save
    @model2 = @model1.model2s.build(model2_params)

    if @model2.save
      redirect_to model1_path(@model1)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

As you can see there's an ugly nested if in the method, and it's not DRY as I'm forced to repeat `render 'new'` in order to capture save failures. This has been the only way I can get `model2` to save, because it requires a relation to `model1`, and `model1` must save first, in order for the id of `model1` to be propagated to the build method.

My question therefore, is how can I refactor this set of code so that it doesn't require a nested if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily make it a single `if`/`else`:

```
if @model1.save && @model1.model2s.build(model2_params).save
  redirect_to @model1
else
  render 'new'
end
```

Alternatively, exceptions:

```
begin
  @model1 = current_user.model1.build(model1_params)
  @model1.save!
  @model2 = @model1.model2s.build(model2_params)
  @model2.save!

  redirect_to @model1
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: I like the use of the && operator, sadly, that didn't work for me. Which I found out after some debugging is because I have a validation that validates the presence of the association (`model1_id`), and because of that the `model2` is considered invalid (as the `model1_id` is `nil` before `model1` is saved). Ideally, neither model1 nor model2 should be created is either is invalid. Which means my code is wrong, funnily enough.

Comment: Then you have larger problems that we can't really solve for you in this question.

Comment: Good point. I'll accept your answer, mainly because I find it more in line with the Rails way of doing things, and I'll open another question with the main issue.

Comment: You should not use exceptions for rescuing validation errors. See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/save-bang-your-head-active-record-will-drive-you-mad/

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Yes, Rails is jam-packed with intentional violations of accepted OOP principles.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  @model1 = current_user.model1.build(model1_params)
  return render("new") unless @model1.save
  @model2 = @model1.model2s.build(model2_params)
  return render("new") unless @model2.save
  redirect_to model1_path(@model1)
end
```

Comment: I considered a solution like this, (`render 'new' and return unless @model1.save`) but rejected it because it doesn't meet the requirement of removing the duplicate `render 'new'` calls. However, I think this is the solution I'd personally use...